# Versão Angular Cli 1.4.5 para Angular Cli mais atual

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

Tenho a versão Angular Cli 1.4.5 que uso em um projeto antigo que esta em produção para um cliente e nunca atualizei para versão mais recente.

Agora preciso fazer novos projetos em Angular 8 e 9, como faço para atualizar meu Angular Cli para versão mais recente ou só mantenho o NodeJS atualizado?

Não quero atualizar o Angular Cli e não poder mais rodar ou fazer build do projeto antigo que tenho cliente que às vezes tem demanda para atualizações.

Answer (score -1):

Mantendo a versão do node, você pode instalar a versão do mais atual do Angular e toda vez que for buildar um versão mais antiga, só você rodar o comando " npm install --force " antes de rodar " ng s " que ele vai "se adequar ao projeto. Eu faço isso nos meus projetos e funciona normalmente.